# C++ Loop Termination Condition

Tags: c++

I need to write a program which asks the user to input characters, until they input a vowel. However, my program always sets the condition to "true" and also does not stop the loop. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    char ch;
    bool condition=false;
    char vow[5];
    vow[0]='a';
    vow[1]='e';
    vow[2]='i';
    vow[3]='o';
    vow[4]='u';

    char arr[1000];
    do
    {   
    condition=false;
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
         cout<<"Enter a character:\n";
         cin>>ch;
         arr[i]=ch;

         for (int k=0;k<5;k++)
         {
            if (ch==(vow[k]))
            {
                condition=true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (condition=false);
}
```

Comment: `while (condition=false)` is an assignment not a test.  Read about "Yoda conditions" which thoroughly explain this category of bug and one approach for preventing it.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's hard to read through all those braces. That's probably the issue you're having. The inner loop will execute 1000 times, no matter how many times you set `condition` to true.

Comment: A sufficiently high compiler warning level will usually report unintended assignments such as this.

Comment: @JohnFilleau you can fix the indentation yourself by clicking on "edit" and tweak whatever you feel needs tweaking. It's as much work as posting a comment.

Comment: @RAM but that doesn't come with the paternalistic finger wagging I oh-so-crave. Plus in this case I think the poor indentation is what allowed OP to make this problem in the first place (lack-of or ignoring compiler warnings aside).

Comment: @JohnFilleau you made me laugh.  Thanks, I needed that.

Comment: Indentation doesn't just help us. In programming the irregular and unexpected are usually bugs. If you follow a regular indentation scheme, I use [Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style), anything that breaks that indentation scheme is probably a bug.

Comment: Good programming practice is to keep the const on left side of condition check like (false == condition). If you forget equak to sign compiler give error.

Comment: thanks for the help everyone. I replaced while (condition=false) with while (x=0), setting it to 1 if the loop returned true. It worked. while (condition=false) was actually an assignment. @JohnFilleau thanks, i really need to work on indentation. Just started C++ and, as you can see, i'm a newbie still =)

Comment: `while (x = 0);` is still assignment. This conditional will always evaluate to `false` and exit.

Comment: For some reason, the program works properly after making that change, though. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

As many have already said in the comments, your the main thing you are doing wrong is that you put `condition=false` in your while head.

> For some reason, the program works properly after making that change, though. Why is that?

What you are doing here is assigning `false` to your variable `condition` and afterwards compare it against `!= 0` which in boolean terms would mean `!= false`.

So as a result you end up with something like this after compiling:
`while((condition = false) != false)` or `while(false != false)`
which evaluates to false and then breaks the loop. Together with your added change of using `break` as soon as you find a vowel, this makes your code 'work'.

Since it seems like you are new to programming here is your code with a few basic suggestions in the comments:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char ch;
  bool condition = false;
  // You can initialize a primitive array in place without having to modify each value
  // individually.
  // Note however, you can not just reassign vow with this array initializer later on
  // but have to do it like you did before
  char vow[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
  char arr[1000];

  // To me it looks like you dont need the do...while loop around the for loop at all,
  // since you seem to want to break out of your loop the first time you find a vowel
  // anyways. Instead consider putting your condition as a seperate check into the
  // for header like this
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000 && !condition; i++) {
    cout << "Enter a character:\n";
    cin >> ch;
    arr[i] = ch;

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
      if (ch == vow[k]) {
        condition = true;
      }
    }
  }

  // Dont forget the return statement. In your case its not really important since the
  // compiler adds return 0 by default, but for testing and such it can be very helpful
  return 0;
}
```

Also, using whitespaces and empty lines improves the readability of your code alot.
Of course, codestyle is always a bit of personal preference but I think everyone can agree to that :D

Comment: There are thousands of questions where someone has mistyped `==` as `=`. It's not worth anyone's time posting detailed answers to them, they should just be closed as typos.

Answer (score -2):

```
do
    {   
       for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter a character:\n";
            cin>>ch;
            arr[i]=ch;

            for (int k=0;k<5;k++)
             {
                if (ch==(vow[k]))
                 {
                  x=1;
                 }
             }

            if (x==0)
            {  
                dis[i]=arr[i]; 
            }

            if(x==1)
            {
                break;
            }   

        count=i;    
        }


    }
    while (x=0);
```

making these changed fixed it. i don't know whether this is due to replacing `while (condition=false)` with `while(x=0)` or because of adding the `if` conditions. Any explanation on that would be appreciated :)

Comment: What you did here does not resolve the error you did before but seems to work 'by accident' and makes your overall code less readable. I posted an answer that hopefully helps you out.